# Embedding bugzilla reports

Tags: bugzilla

I am trying to find a way to embed bugzilla's tabular reports in another HTML document. Does anyone know a way to do this? All embedding must happen client-side. I don't have access to backend web server to implement parsing/inlining of contenting. I figure, I could use an iframe, but i haven't found a way to tell bugzilla not to emit its standard header and footer.

Does anyone have experience embedding bugzilla reports into an HTML document on the client side?

Here is an example report... https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/report.cgi?x_axis_field=bug_status&y_axis_field=bug_severity&z_axis_field=&query_format=report-table&short_desc_type=allwordssubstr&short_desc=&classification=Technology&product=Sapphire&target_milestone=0.3&longdesc_type=allwordssubstr&longdesc=&bug_file_loc_type=allwordssubstr&bug_file_loc=&status_whiteboard_type=allwordssubstr&status_whiteboard=&keywords_type=allwords&keywords=&emailtype1=substring&email1=&emailtype2=substring&email2=&bug_id_type=anyexact&bug_id=&votes=&chfieldfrom=&chfieldto=Now&chfieldvalue=&format=table&action=wrap&field0-0-0=noop&type0-0-0=noop&value0-0-0=

Answer (score 1):

You want the `&format=simple` parameter on your buglist request, e.g.:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?bug_id=1000,1001,1002&format=simple

Put a URL like that (to your Bugzilla, naturally) in the `src` attribute of an <iframe>.

Gerv

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work with reports (as opposed to buglist queries). See the URL that I added to the question.

Comment: format=simple for charts seems to have broken at some point. :-( I believe you can fix it by removing the following line of code around line 250 of report.cgi on trunk Bugzilla:

`$formatparam = '';`

Answer (score 0):

A little javascript to request the html and enough parsing to find the right snippet might be your only option.
http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/ might be a good parsing option.